# How to check command-line parameter from a PowerShell module?

Tags: powershell, parameters, module, scope

Is there a way to check if a command-line parameter was specified for a PowerShell script from a module (.psm1 file)? I do not need the value, just have to know if the parameter was specified. The `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey` method does not seem to work.

TestParam.psm1:

```
function Test-ScriptParameter {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ()
    # This does not work (always returns false):
    return $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('MyParam')
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

TestParam.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $MyParam= "Default"
)

$path = Join-Path (Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Parent) 'TestParam.psm1'
Import-Module $path -ErrorAction Stop -Force

Test-ScriptParameter
```

This must return `false`:

```
PS>.\TestParam.ps1
```

This must return `true`:

```
PS>.\TestParam.psq -MyParam ""
```

This must return `true`:

```
PS>.\TestParam.ps1 -MyParam "Runtime"
```

Comment: This seems like a poor design.  Your module/function shouldn't have a dependency on the caller like this.  Is this a possible [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @boxdog: Its not an X-Y problem to be precise but yes I do understand what you meant.. Alek: Can you explain the need of this approach?

Comment: I am writing a comandlet that reads a config file and populates script's variables from config file settings. I want the code to check if a setting present in the config file was also specified via command line and if so, give the command line a preference. E.g. if the script was invoked with the -MyParam XYZ, and the MyParam setting in the config file was set to ABC, the value of the $MyParam in the script would be XYZ. I know, generally what I want to do would not be kosher, but in my particular case, it is needed.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do: https://github.com/alekdavis/ConfigFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done like you are thinking about it. The `PSBoundParameters` variable is native to the cmdlet's execution and as such depends on the `param` block of the cmdlet's definition. So in your case, the `Test-ScriptParameter` is checking if it was invoked with the parameter `MyParam` but since it doesn't specify it, then it will be always `false`.

To achieve what I believe you want, you need to create a function that checks into a hash structure like the `PSBoundParameters` for a specific key. The key needs to be provided by name. But then a simple `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('MyParam')` wherever you need it should suffice.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I understand how $PsBoundParameters works. I was hoping there were a way to get script's $PSBoundParameters from a module cmdlet, but looks like it's not an option.

Comment: There is like this `@PSBoundParametets` but the issue is that the cmdled being called must have specified a valid matching parameter set. It is therefore impossible to create something generic. Within some modules, this trick is used to invoke a private cmdlet with matching parameter sets with a very simple code. Depending on your intentions, you might be able to achieve the same by control and limitation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are checking the `$PSBoundParameters` value of the Function itself, which has no parameters.

You could make the function work by sending the `$PSBoundParameters` variable from the script in to the function via a differently named parameter.

For example:

TestParam.psm1:

```
function Test-ScriptParameter ($BoundParameters) {
    return $BoundParameters.ContainsKey('MyParam')
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

TestParam.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $MyParam = "Default"
)

$path = Join-Path (Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Parent) 'TestParam.psm1'
Import-Module $path -ErrorAction Stop -Force


Test-ScriptParameter $PSBoundParameters
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this was a simplified example just to illustrate the problem. The real function has its own parameters, so I do not want to introduce additional parameter, since it's not something the caller would need to know anything about (it's only needed for internal logic, as I explained in the comment above).